# pyserial - I can't read from port

Tags: python, pyserial, tty, ftdi

thanks in advance.

I'm trying to read from a serial device using **future technology devices international ltd bridge(i2c/spi/uart/fifo)**.

The device is designed to only send data. It has been tested in a Windows environment and is working correctly.

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS with the **pyserial** python module as follow:

```
import serial

ser = serial.Serial(
            port ='/dev/ttyUSB0',
            baudrate=38400,
            parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,
            stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
            bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,
            timeout=5
)

buff = ser.read(128)
print buff

ser.close()
```

When I run the script I can't read anything from the device. Do you have any idea or suggestion?

Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: Try changing the timeout, and also make sure the baud rate is correct.  Additionally, ensure that `ttyUSB0` is the correct port; sometimes it changes from device to device.

Comment: Hi Ctrl S, thank you for your suggestions. If I don't set the timeout the script get stuck. The baud rate was given by the person who designed the device. The port ttyUSB0 is the correct one, I connect and disconnect the device and that is the id that appears and disappears.

Comment: Keep the timeout, but try lowering it.  I have used 0.1 and 0.15 for a baud rate of 38400 in the past.
Though, if you're getting no data at all and your timeout is already high, maybe the timeout is not the issue...
All else I can suggest at the moment is to ensure the rest of the parameters are correct.  I don't remember enough about my serial experiences to provide a proper answer at this time.

Comment: The only difference I can spot between my 38400 serial setup and yours, besides the port, is that I use a timeout of 0.15

Comment: Hi again Ctr S, thank you for your reply, now it works in some cases and in other not. I'm going to keep trying, if you have another further suggestion I would really appreciate it.

Comment: What are some examples of these cases?